# Is it possible to write a T-SQL query with multiple params for the same column that use AND instead of OR ? (and to do it dynamically)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with some long varchar and I want to search for specific rows that contain multiple parameters.

So let's say I have article 1 with the long varchar being AVJ4I4LNK45Y0GEHV023. Then I have a list with the following parameters: AVJ, LNK, GEH. I want to be able to identify the rows that contain all these parameters.

So basically I would do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE description like '%AVJ%' AND
      description like '%LNK%' AND
      description like '%GEH%'
```

This works alright, but the problem is that I don't know how many parameters I'm going to have. Because I extract the parameters from an Excel spreadsheet and try to find the rows that match with these parameters.

The only reasonable way I found is CONTAINS(NEAR...) but right now I have SQL SERVER 2014 Express Edition and the full text search feature is not supported with this version.

So right now I'm stuck in t-sql, trying to create a procedure that would add all my {column like '%param%'} in a loop or something, but it's not really working.

Is it at least doable in t-sql or am I taking the dead end route ?
I know I'm not even suppose to do that because of SQL Injection but I don't see any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to construct the query using a `values` statement and use `join` and `group by`:

```
SELECT p.ProductId
FROM Products p JOIN
     (VALUES ('AVJ'), ('LNK'), ('GEH')) vals(v)
     ON p.description LIKE '%' + vals.v + '%'
GROUP BY p.ProductId
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECDT COUNT(*) FROM vals);
```

You could then generalize this using `split()` or some other method to convert a string to a table:

```
WITH vals(v) as (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.split(@vals, ',')
     )
    SELECT p.ProductId
    FROM Products p JOIN
         vals
         ON p.description LIKE '%' + vals.v + '%'
    GROUP BY p.ProductId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vals);
```

You can Google `SQL Server split` to get an implementation of a `split()` function.

Comment: Works :) I was trying it with those made-up values I gave and it wasn't returning anything :P Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Load the excel file into a table (SSIS or you can use OPENROWSET).

```
WITH conditionCountCTE (
  -- Get the count of conditions
  SELECT COUNT(*) conditionCount FROM excelTable
)
, ProductIDCTE (
  -- Find out how many conditions match
  SELECT ProductID
  FROM Product
  INNER JOIN excelTable
    ON Product.description LIKE N'%' + excelTable.condition + N'%'
  GROUP BY ProductID
  -- Get only those records where the condition count equals to match count
  HAVING COUNT(*) = conditionCountCTE.conditionCount
)
-- Get the data
SELECT
 *
FROM
 Products P
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM ProductIDCTE PCTE WHERE PCTE.ProductID = P.ProductID
)
```